# What is the purpose of passport local

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, passport.js

I'm having a hard time understanding the whole point of using passport when using a local database.

What is the whole point of serializing, deserializing, creating a login strategy, creating a register strategy, having the req.isAuthenticated() middleware, and req.logout()?

It seems much simpler for me to make my own middleware where I just assign a property to req.session to check for a logged in user. I can also sign a user out with req.session.destroy().

Am I missing something really trivial?

Comment: The [tag:passport] tag is rather ambiguous. I guess your question is about a library or framework, could you please clarify that?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález http://passportjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Almost all apps are going to have a local strategy. You're right, if you're only going to use the local strategy, then why bother using Passport?

However, if you're also wanting a Facebook, Google and Twitter strategy, for example, then it makes sense to have your local strategy using the same middleware.